autodesk-platform-services viewer ASP.NET Framework
These links contain tutorial and code in ASP.NET CORE & Visual Studio 2022 for simple viewer that allows us to upload, translate and view 3D designs and 2D drawings.
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-dotnet
Is there a link with tutorial and code in ASP.NET Framework 4.7/4.8 & Visual Studio 2022?

We don't have a link to Simple Viewer tutorial using .NET Framework 4.7/4.8.
We focused on LTS versions in our tutorials, that's why you see them using .NET 6 currently.
To build a similar app using .NET Framework 4.7/4.8 you'll need to modify the server configuration, but note that the SDKs used in the tutorials are compatible with .NET Framework, so you can use the same logic for connecting with APS APIs.
